# Power BI Testreport: Failed Testrun without Bug

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi

want to report failed test runs without related bug. Think a really detailed entity relationship diagram of the Devops data bases will give the answer. Unfortunately I found only parts that don't answer my question.

Thanks for any hint that kicks me forward.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this document below to do it:
[Connect to Analytics data by using the Power BI OData feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/access-analytics-power-bi?view=azure-devops)

Simple steps:

1. Open PowerBI
2. Get data > Other > Odata feed
3. Specify URL, format: [https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_odata/v3.0-preview/](https://analytics.dev.azure.com/%7BOrganizationName%7D/_odata/v3.0-preview/)
4. Connect (You may choose Basic and specify Personal access token)
5. Select related table, for example:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I already have done what you suggested. Now I've loads of tables with some relationships. But it is not clear to me how - starting from a TestSuite and the containing TestPoints - I can find an associated bug. Via the TestCase I find all bugs associated to this TestCase but I only want the bug of this specific TestPoint in this specific TestSuite.

Comment: @JoeKiting Based on my researching, it is not supported to find all bugs associated to test point in specific test suite through OData feed. I'd suggest that you could submit user voice [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea)